# find out whether wi-fi is enabled and connected

Tags: java, android

I've found this answer on so many answers here on SO :

I'm checking whether user has wi-fi enabled and is connected when he chooses the spinner option(drop down menu).

```
private static boolean isConnected(Context context, AdapterView<?> parent) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
        if (connectivityManager != null) {
            networkInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        }
        return networkInfo == null ? false : networkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

It's not working for me, I must have forgotten some permissions in Manifest what else am I 
missing?

Or is it better that I use `WifiManager` does anyone have example for that ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the permission `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE` in your Manifest and `android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` if you want to read the cellular network state.

Comment: You might also need `android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE`